# Jq parsing : Selecting an object from a list of objects based on criteria

Tags: jq

I have a JSON like this.

```
{
  "servers": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "addresses": {
        "services_z1": [
          {
            "OS-EXT-IPS-MAC:mac_addr": "fa:16:3e:bc:db:7d",
            "addr": "10.3.3.18",
            "version": 4,
            "OS-EXT-IPS:type": "fixed"
          }
        ]
      }

    },

    {
      "id": "2",
      "addresses": {
        "services_z1": [
          {
            "OS-EXT-IPS-MAC:mac_addr": "fa:16:3e:bc:db:7d",
            "addr": "10.3.3.19",
            "version": 4,
            "OS-EXT-IPS:type": "fixed"
          }
        ]
      }

    },

    {
      "id": "3",
      "addresses": {
        "services_z1": [
          {
            "OS-EXT-IPS-MAC:mac_addr": "fa:16:3e:bc:db:7d",
            "addr": "10.3.3.20",
            "version": 4,
            "OS-EXT-IPS:type": "fixed"
          }
        ]
      }

    },

    {
      "id": "4",
      "addresses": {
        "services_z1": [
          {
            "OS-EXT-IPS-MAC:mac_addr": "fa:16:3e:bc:db:7d",
            "addr": "10.3.3.21",
            "version": 4,
            "OS-EXT-IPS:type": "fixed"
          }
        ]
      }

    }

    ]

}
```

I am trying to find the server id for which the addr value is 10.3.3.18. How can I achieve that?

I know that it would be something like jq '.servers[] | select(some criteria)'

But I am not able ot form that criteria.

Any pointer would be of huge help.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it resolves your question.

Comment: Hey Paul, Thanks for your answer. Sorry I was out of station for a week, I shall check and let you know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want something like the following:

```
jq '.servers[]|select(.addresses.services_z1[].addr=="10.3.3.18")|.id'
```

This says to look through all of the servers, match those that have .addresses.services_z1[].addr=="10.3.3.18", and then print the id of those servers.

Comment: Hi Paul, in my JSON there are some servers which does not have services_z1 node under the addresses node at all. The current query gives error jq: error: Cannot iterate over null. How can we make it better

Comment: I tried this
".servers[] | select(.addresses.services_z1 != null) | select(.addresses.services_z1[].addr==\"$FIXED_IP\") | .id"

This works for me as I am filtering out those having no node named services_z1 under addresses.